# How to style Link from the react-dom-router module?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, styled-components

I am trying to specifically style `:visited`, but it has no effect. It seems to me that when the component is rendered it comes with the status of: visited.

```
export const Hyperlink = styled(Link)`
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin: 0 2rem 0 2rem;
  color: #b3b3b3;

  :visited {
    color: red;
  }

  :hover {
    color: white;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
  }
`;
```

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to style the currently selected link?

Comment: So what I want to do is pretty simple. If he is not "clicked" he will have one style, if he is "clicked" he will have another. The problem that is occurring is that the selector: visited is activated even when reloading the page, by default Link already comes this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do, for those who want to know, I did the following:

**INDEX:**

```
 <Hyperlink
            key={info.name}
            exact
            to={info.to}
            activeStyle={{ color: "white" }}
          >
            {info.name}
          </Hyperlink>
```

**STYLES**

```
  export const Hyperlink = styled(NavLink)`
      font-family: "Circular-Bold";
      font-size: 0.8rem;
      color: ${Colors.greyLight};
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 0.16em;

      &:hover {
        color: white;
      }

      &.active {
        &::after {
          content: "";
          height: 0.13rem;
          width: 2rem;
          background-color: ${Colors.greenLight};
          display: block;
          margin: 0.4rem auto;
        }
      }
    `;
```

I used the `activeStyle` property according to the documentation and also noticed that it creates a class named "`active`" in activated `NavLink`, so I used it to create content.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [simple example of the docs](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-elements#usage).

You are forgetting `&` before `hover` and `visited`.

```
export const Hyperlink = styled(Link)`
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin: 0 2rem 0 2rem;
  color: #b3b3b3;

  /* added & */
  &:visited {
    color: red;
  }

  /* added & */
  &:hover {
    color: white;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
  }
`;
```

Comment: I have not forgotten, according to the documentation do: hover or &: hover in the case of styled-component is the same thing, and already tested with both modes and Link is not stylized in: visited. It seems that Link already comes active even without clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

To style the active link you can add a class to the active on like this

```
<NavLink to="/path" activeClassName="selected">
    Link
</NavLink>
```

This will add a class selected to the currently selected tab.

Or you can do this to directly style it

```
<NavLink
    to="/path"
    activeStyle={{=
        color: "red"
    }}
>
  Link
</NavLink>
```

Just take note that you need to use the `NavLink` component.

See the docs [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink/activeclassname-string)

Comment: I have not forgotten, according to the documentation do: hover or &: hover in the case of styled-component is the same thing, and already tested with both modes and Link is not stylized in: visited. It seems that Link already comes active even without clicking on it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that? Are you looking to style the current tab?

Comment: yes, what I want to do is simple. Clicking on the hyperlink will turn white and the hr below it will be displayed, clicking on another hyperlink (the first one clicked will be disabled) and the same will happen to the second.

Comment: Yes that was it! But one detail was missing. I have an hr inside my Hyperlink component. And it needs to be displayed when it is activated (only when it is or is enabled). Since my component does not render with each click, how should I activate it?

Comment: Is the hr there to create an underline for the selected tab? If yes you can replicate it with adding an :after element if selected. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

use the `&`

```
export const Hyperlink = styled(Link)`
...

  &:visited {
   ...
  }

  &:hover {
    ...
  }
`;
```

Comment: I have not forgotten, according to the documentation do: hover or &: hover in the case of styled-component is the same thing, and already tested with both modes and Link is not stylized in: visited. It seems that Link already comes active even without clicking on it.